# HTTP 404 not found(Servlet not found)

Tags: java, jsp, http, tomcat, servlets

I am a student learning to build Web Application using jsp and servlets. My Web Application project was working fine since a month but today suddenly its behaving weird. When I am submitting my jsp page, it is not able to find my servlet. I have used **servlet annotation** to map the request.

**Following is my jsp:-**

```
<form name=registration_form action="<%=application.getContextPath() %>/Registration" method="post">  
    First Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="firstName" required/></td></tr> 
    </form>
```

**Following is my Servlet:-**

```
package servlets;
    @WebServlet("/Registration")
    public class Registration extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        public Registration() {
            super();
        }

        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            String firstName=request.getParameter("firstName"); 
            System.out.println(firstName);
        }
    }
```

**Following is my web.xml:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Login</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**Following is my Project Hierarchy:-**

[image]

**Following is the error:-**

```
HTTP Status 404 - /Login/Registration
type Status report

message /Login/Registration

description The requested resource is not available.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
```

**Following is my console log:-**

```
Mar 11, 2014 11:30:33 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin;C:\windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.6.0_17/bin/../jre/bin/client;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.6.0_17/bin/../jre/bin;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.6.0_17/bin/../jre/lib/i386;C:\Program Files (x86)\PC Connectivity Solution\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\DLLShared\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\OEM\DLLShared\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\OEM\DLLShared\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\OEM\12.0\DLLShared\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Roxio\OEM\AudioCore\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.3.4\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;D:\mongodb\bin;D:\development tools\apache-maven-3.1.1-bin\apache-maven-3.1.1\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\;D:\development tools\eclipse;;.
Mar 11, 2014 11:30:33 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Login' did not find a matching property.
Mar 11, 2014 11:30:34 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Mar 11, 2014 11:30:34 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Mar 11, 2014 11:30:34 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1071 ms
Mar 11, 2014 11:30:34 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Mar 11, 2014 11:30:34 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
Mar 11, 2014 11:30:35 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Mar 11, 2014 11:30:35 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Mar 11, 2014 11:30:35 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1463 ms
```

Comment: the problem is its not finding the path , try this `action=" ./Registration"`

Comment: @sankrish It is finding the right path i.e "http://localhost:8080/Login/Registration" but still giving me error. This app suddenly started to give error, before that it was working fine

Comment: you have your servlet inside `servlets` package right . But it points the path of source packages

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had suffered this problem too.
Whenever we delete a tomcat server and run our project in new one without build classpaths and clean and build that project, we got this type of exceptions.

So, Build your projects classpath.
Goto property of your Project then Select =>Java Build Path => Order and Export.
Select All classpaths.

Comment: Cleaning all projects works too.

Comment: for me it is my first project and I had the samed issue

Answer (score 2):

Your Servlet path is `/Registration` but your request points to `/Login/Registration`.

You need to your form's action attribute to follow.

```
action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Registration"
```

or

```
action="/Registration"
```

Comment: on action i have specified the same application.getContextPath() %>/Registration

Comment: Verify whether your application.getContextPath() resolves to http://localhost:8080/AppName/ or http://localhost:8080/AppName/Login/

Answer (score 2):

use this format in your jsp action page:

```
action="/Registration"
```

and the webpage:

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Registration</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>packagename.Registration</servlet-class>
</servlet> 
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Registration</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/Registration</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

[follow this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)

Comment: It is not required as I have used servlet annotation